# Getting coverage from jest testing with mocks

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I seem unable to get jest coverage for reporting when I try to use mocks.  Scenario is:

```html
// file.js

export func1 () {}; // there are many named exports in this file

export apifunc () {}; // this is the function I have mocked
```

```html
// __mocks__/file.js

export apifunc () {}; // mocked version of apifunc for testing
```

```html
// file.test.js
import {func0, /*apifunc*/} from './file.js';

// jest.mock('./file.js) - this did not work due to only one mocked function from file.js in a sea of named exports.  It would cause all my other tests to fail.

import { apifunc } from './__mocks__/file.js; // this is what I ended up having to do

test('test the apifunc here', () => {
  // tests all pass
});
```

I have not been able to get code coverage on the apifunc and have not been able to find a good answer

Comment: Provide the code you want to test and cover